# How do I hide more filter button on specific devices?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a filter. In lg devices, I want to make use of more filter button and hide hello world 3,4,5 inside the more filter button. Whereas, in md devices I do not want the more filter button and want to load the complete content.

Is this possible? If so, can someone help me achieve it?

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>


    <div class="row mb-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Hello world</p>
        <p>Hello world 1</p>
        <p>Hello world 2</p>
        <button id="more-filters" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreFilters" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="moreFilters">More filters</button>
        
    <div class="collapse" id="moreFilters">
      <p>Hello world 3</p>
      <p>Hello world 4</p>
      <p>Hello world 5</p>
    </div>
        
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use @media query & add specific styles

Comment: I doubt this can be possible via CSS because more filter button remains on all screen size. Is there any working example you can provide with the trick you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The below code hides the button on extra small, small, and medium devices and show it on large and extra-large devices.

You have to use Javascript/Jquery to remove the class "collapse" from element with id moreFilters on the medium device and add it on a large device.

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>

<script>
$(window).on('resize', function() {
if($(window).height() > 992) {
    $('#moreFilters').addClass('collapse');
}else{
    $('#moreFilters').removeClass('collapse');
}
})
</script>

    <div class="row mb-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Hello world</p>
        <p>Hello world 1</p>
        <p>Hello world 2</p>
        <button id="more-filters" class="btn btn-primary btn-block d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreFilters" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="moreFilters">More filters</button>
        
    <div class="collapse" id="moreFilters">
      <p>Hello world 3</p>
      <p>Hello world 4</p>
      <p>Hello world 5</p>
    </div>
        
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear but the idea of asking here is not to duplicate content. I already knew this way sir.

Comment: This just hides the more filter button and the content inside is also hidden with it. So the purpose is still not fulfilled. On smaller devices I needed all the content loaded without more filter button and on larger devices with more filter onclick without duplicating the content.

Comment: I don't think you looked at the updated answer. The content is not duplicated.

Comment: Sir but the purpose is not fulfilled either. If you notice your answer in smaller devices the content inside the button is also hidden. So how do I ensure that only the button gets hidden but not the content inside it? So in short, the collapse function is not required in smaller devices.

Comment: The string "More filters" is what you are saying as the content inside the button?